# Wrong result printed after calculating the volume of a sphere

Tags: c, calculation, radius

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PI 3.141592f
#define RADIUS 10.0f

int main(void)
{
    float volume;
    
    volume = (4.0f/3.0f) * PI * (RADIUS * RADIUS * RADIUS);
    printf("Volume: %d\n", volume);

    return 0;
}
```

It's wrongly printing the value `536870912`.

What am I doing wrong? As far as I know, the math is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%d` is for printing `int`, so passing `float` to that invokes *undefined behavior*.

You should use `%f` or `%g` to print `float`.